# Visualize git commit diff similarly to mergetool

Tags: vimdiff, git

I've been thinking of ways to visualize git commits with vim. I would like to be able to:

1. run a command from the terminal such as: `vimdiff -c <commit id>`.
2. vim opens with two windows on a vertical split layout, displaying a diff the changes introduced for one of the files on that particular commit.
3. each file opens on a different tab, so I can press `gt` to view the diff for the next file.

I can't possibly be the first to think of this issue, but I couldn't find any plugin or information out there. So how do you guys do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git provides this functionality for you.

First set up git to use Vim as its "difftool". (Depending on what you have installed, this step may be unnecessary: vimdiff is one of Git's default difftools.)

```
git config diff.tool vimdiff
```

Then run git's `difftool` command with appropriate options. e.g. to view the changes introduced by commit `12345abc`, you can use either

```
git difftool 12345abc^..12345abc
```

or its shorthand

```
git difftool 12345abc^!
```

By default this will open the files one at a time. After you quit Vim, Git will open the next comparison. [Here are a selection of ways](https://superuser.com/questions/455944/vimdiff-and-git-all-at-once) to get Git instead to open all the diffs at once.